# Inline-block element next row not coming properly

Tags: css

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>

.div1{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
 border:1px solid red;
 height:250px;
}

.div2{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
 
 border:1px solid red;
}


.div3{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
 border:1px solid red;
 vertical-align:top;
 
}


.div4{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
 border:1px solid red;
}
</style>
```

```html
<html>
<head>




</head>
<body>
 


 
 
 <div class="div1">
  some content1
</div><!-- 
--><div class="div2">
  some content2
</div><!-- 
--><div class="div3">
  some content3
</div><!-- 
--><div class="div4">
  some content4
</div>
 



<body>

</html>
```

There is gap between column2 and column4 how to remove this gap. between column2 and column 4.I have attached image for understand once I want to align my div4 after my div2 but there is blank space create between div2 and div4.

I want to put my div4 after div2 .I am new to design not able to understand this behaviour.

Comment: You may also try this with flexbox:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45666315/3362989

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col1, .col2 {
    width: 49%;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}

.col2 {
    margin-left: 49%;
}

.div1, .div2, .div3, .div4 {
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.div1 {
    height:250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col1">
    <div class="div1">some content1</div>
    <div class="div3">some content3</div>
</div>
<div class="col2">
    <div class="div2">some content2</div>
    <div class="div4">some content4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes you give correct ans.but i wan to fill gap between div2 and div4 with inline-block.Is there any way ?

Comment: where is gap between div2 and div4?

Comment: your mean is gap between div1 and div2?

Comment: I want to produce same result as you give the ans. but instead of float I want to use Inline-block

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving aswer. have a nice day thanks again